# Rust function to take only an Iterator that holds structs that impl Ord?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits

I want to write a rust function that takes as a parameter an Iterator, but I only want Iterators that hold things with Ord.

Here is what I have tried:

```rust
    fn my_fn<U>(&self, foo: U<T>)
        where
            U: Iterator
    {
        /* */
    }
```

At the top of the implementation block, I have a where clause that says T must have Ord:

```rust
impl<T> SortedVec<T> 
    where
        T: Ord,
{
```

but still I get the error:

```
error[E0109]: type arguments are not allowed on type parameter `U`
  --> src\main.rs:53:31
   |
53 |     fn my_fn<U>(&self, foo: U<T>)
   |                             - ^ type argument not allowed
   |                             |
   |                             not allowed on type parameter `U`
   |
note: type parameter `U` defined here
  --> src\main.rs:53:14
   |
53 |     fn my_fn<U>(&self, foo: U<T>)
   |
```

If I don't specify that U (the type with iterator) holds on objects of type T (with ord), that causes problems down the line when I try to take things out of the U object and try to use Ord methods on them. What can I do?

Comment: `Iterator` uses an associated type [`Item`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#associatedtype.Item) to specify the type of items it produces: `fn my_fn<U>(&self, foo: U)  where U: Iterator<Item = T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to ask two separate questions:

- How to take an iterator whose items implement a specific trait
- How to take an iterator whose items are of a specific type

If you want a specific type, use:

```rust
pub struct SortedVec<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T> SortedVec<T>
where
    T: Ord,
{
    pub fn my_fn<U>(&self, foo: U)
    where
        U: Iterator<Item = T>,
    {
        /* */
    }
}
```

or the short form:

```rust
pub struct SortedVec<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T> SortedVec<T>
where
    T: Ord,
{
    pub fn my_fn(&self, foo: impl Iterator<Item = T>) {
        /* */
    }
}
```

---

If you on the other hand want a generic type that implements a specific trait (like in the title of your question), use this:

```rust
pub fn my_fn<T>(foo: T)
where
    T: Iterator,
    <T as Iterator>::Item: Ord,
{
    // Sample code that requires `Ord`
    let mut items = foo.collect::<Vec<_>>();
    items.sort();
}
```